# Python. Как завершить программу при выполнении условия if (текстовый квест без использования циклов)

Tags: python, if, break

Есть задание написать текстовый квест. Написать используя только if, elife, else. Например по сюжету игрок выбирает одно из двух действий. если он выбрал if, то игра продолжается, а если второе условие, то программа должна вывести сообщение о конце игры и всё, т.е. дальше она не продолжается и никакие сообщения больше не выводит. Как это сделать с циклами знаю. А вот использую только условные операторы - нет. Есть ли какое-то подобии break?

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то Вам должен помочь пустой `return`

Comment: *elif(опечатка)

Comment: Цикл `while` и `for` вы не можете использовать?

Comment: @strawdog , в заголовке вопроса же написано, что без использования циклов

Comment: нет. в задании только можно использовать if/elif....

Comment: Меня интересует логика продолжения игры. Если ответ игрока не подразумевает завершение игры, как она продолжается?

Comment: Только учусь. Поэтому еще не знаю, можно ли использовать такую конструкцию: персонаж квеста на определенном этапе просит выбрать один из двух предметов(чтобы помочь ему). Если игрок выбирает первый предмет и он оказывается не правильным, то хотелось бы, чтобы на выводе было сообщение "игра окончена" и всё как бы конец, дальше ничего не происходит. А вот если игрок выбирает предмет 2, то уже выполняются дальнейшие действия в условии. Вот интересно, так вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете завершить процесс выполнения вашего квеста когда это нужно при помощи `sys.exit()`

```
import sys

sys.exit()
```

Вы также можете выдать в консоль коментарий выхода из программы

```
import sys

sys.exit("you dead")
```

### Но

Это действие завершит выполнение скрипта вообще

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это будет не удобно, но попробуйте использовать флаг, например

```
go = o #gameover
if go != 1 and someelse:
    somecode
elif go != 1 and someelse: #в этом условии игрок проиграл
    somecode
    go = 1
    print('гамовер')
elif go != 1 and someelse:
    somecode
else:
    somecode
```

пожалуста обьясните мне как оформить код в комментарии)

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо. Можешь рассказать как оформить код в такую вставку?

Comment: Выделить и нажать на кнопку «код».